# swapping drives

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have a  box with three disks: `sda`, `sdb`, and `sdc`. `sda` hosts partitions for windows vista and xubuntu 16.04 system root `/`. `sdc` is mounted to `/home`, and `sdb` contains a `swap` partition, and a partition mounted to `/media/data`. The `sdb` disk is inconsequential.

A friend asked me to pull data from a HD that contains personal items, and to transfer it to a portable HD. I feel responsible, and want to get this right.

Can i swap `sdb` for my friend's HD, without reinstalling linux? Is it necessary to remove `sdb` from `fstab`, or should i do the operation in windows, which cannot see `sdb`. The system boots using grub2: can I be sure it wont get pissed off?

Comment: So your friend gave you a hard drive with personal files that they want you to transfer to transfer to a portable HD, and your going to use sdb as this portable HD. Is this correct? Also, when you say that the sdb disk is inconsequential, do you mean that the files on /media/data aren't important? By default, there's no /media/data, so the only files there would be ones you added. Finally, post the output of `cat /etc/fstab` so we can tell you which lines to comment out if you want to remove sdb

Comment: From your question I presume that your friend's drive is an internal drive connected via (S)ATA, hence why you want/need to remove one of your computer's internal drives to be able to connect your friend's. Is that correct?

Comment: My friend's HD is indeed a SATA, and I need to remove `sdb` so I can insert it in my box and mount it. `sdb` only contains data and the swap, but nothing essential to either linux or windows.  I can post the output of `cat /etc/fstab` tonight when I get back home. However, if all that is required is commenting out the `sdb` partitions, I can do this myself. I was, however, scared that grub might get confused by the change in hardware.